# Number of Symmetric matrices of fix rank over finite fields

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, lie-algebras, multilinear-algebra

This might be a question that shouldn't be asked here. But I need some help.
I want to count the number of $n\times n$ symmetric matrices over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and rank $r$. I found the following note

http://www.math.clemson.edu/~kevja/REU/2004/SymmetricRankRMatrices.pdf

But I think the formula given here is not correct. For example, it says that the number of symmetric matrices of rank $n$ is given by 
$$q^{{n \choose 2}}\prod\limits_{j=0}^s\left(1-(\frac{1}{q})^{2j-1}\right)$$

where $s=\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor$. But this is not matching with the simplest case, i.e. when $n=1$. Is there any other reference?

Answer (score 7):

The number of symmetric matrices of a given rank over a finite field is computed in Theorem 2 in the following article.

- J. MacWilliams: [Orthogonal matrices over finite fields](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317262?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

In particular, the number of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices of full rank with entries in $\mathbb{F}_q$ is equal to
$$q^{\binom{n+1}{2}}\prod_{1\leq i\leq n\atop i \, odd}\left(1-\frac{1}{q^i}\right).$$

This number agrees with the formula in the the linked REU article modulo a typo.

Comment: For some further information and references, see the solution to Exercise 1.198 of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, second ed.

Comment: Thanks. The article of MacWilliams seems interesting. I did not know about it.

Comment: @Singh If this answer is sufficient for you, then you can accept it, so that people reading MathOverflow will know that the question doesn't still need to be answered.

Comment: @Zach Teitler Yes, the given answers are sufficient. I apologize as I did not know I had to accept it.

Comment: @Singh I think Zach Teitler is referring to the formal process of [accepting answers](https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers).